# 500 Internal Server Error when hosted .net Core App in Docker

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core

I have created a test app in .net Core Framework and was perfectly running in a development environment.

Later I published this to docker container and is perfectly working as my declared IP address with hosted are listening and I can browse it through google chrome.

But when I try to consume API service I am not able to do so.  I have created to simple function to calculate the sum of two numbers.

Below are my configurations

Program.cs

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls(Configuration["Hosting:https:host"] + ":" + Configuration["Hosting:https:port"], Configuration["Hosting:http:host"] + ":" + Configuration["Hosting:http:port"])
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.ListenAnyIP(int.Parse(Configuration["Hosting:https:port"].ToString()), listenOptions =>
                {
            var serverCertificate = LoadCertificate();
            listenOptions.UseHttps(serverCertificate); // <- Configures SSL
            });
            options.ListenAnyIP(int.Parse(Configuration["Hosting:http:port"].ToString()));

                //options.ListenLocalhost(5004, opts => opts.UseHttps());
                //options.ListenLocalhost(5005, opts => opts.UseHttps());


                //options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
                //options.ListenLocalhost(port, listenOptions =>
                //{
                //    var serverCertificate = LoadCertificate();
                //    listenOptions.UseHttps(serverCertificate); // <- Configures SSL
                //});
            })
        .UseSerilog()
        .Build();
    }
```

Comment: Your app has actions with views and actions that return data (api) and you can access the actions with views (with chrome) but you get an error when you try to access the action that return data. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you share the API method which you trying to call? As from chrome you able to view pages right then make a dummy get method and try to consume from chrome,

Comment: And please include an error message. If you get a 500 response there should be an exception. Afaik the default configuratino should log them to console so you can see the logs with kubectl logs [mypod].

Comment: "I am not able to do so" is not a problem statement that we can help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the error.

Please confirm the below configuration.

Is environment variables are defined if used? If not please define it in Dockerfile.